# Skipping if statements within a while loop

Tags: c

I am making a program that has the user take a random quiz of three. I also want to ask the user if they would like to go again and take a different quiz. I have put it all together and after I ask the user if they would like to go again, the quizzes in the if statements are skipped.

```
int main(void) {

    srand(time(0));

    int luckyNumber;
    int quizNumber;
    float score;
    float overallScore;
    int averageScore;
    float attempts;
    int i;
    char answer1;
    char answer2;
    char answer3[10];
    char quiz1Ans3[10] = "yes";
    char quiz2Ans3[10] = "yes";
    char quiz3Ans3[10] = "yes";
    char loop = 'y';
    int preval = 0;
    float finalScore;

    printf("Welcome to the quiz program!\n");
    while(loop == 'y') {
        printf("Please enter a lucky number between 1 and 9: ");
        scanf("%d", &luckyNumber);
        quizNumber = rand() % 3 + 1;
        
        while(preval == quizNumber){
        quizNumber = rand() % 3 + 1;
        }
        printf("Your quiz number is %d\n", quizNumber);

        if (quizNumber == 1) {
            attempts = 0;
            while (overallScore != 100) { 
                attempts++;
                score = 0;
                overallScore=0;
                printf("Quiz 1\n"); 
                printf("Question 1\n"); 
                //question 
                printf("A. True\n");
                printf("B. False\n");
                printf("Enter your answer: ");
                scanf(" %c", &answer1);
            
                if (answer1 == 'B' || answer1 == 'b') {
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    score += 5;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Incorrect!, Try again.\n");  
                    printf("\n");       
                }
                   
                printf("Question 2\n");
                //question
                printf("A. \n");
                printf("B. \n");
                printf("C. \n");
                printf("D. \n");
                printf("Enter your answer: ");
                scanf(" %c", &answer2);

                if (answer2 == 'B' || answer2 == 'b') {
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    score += 5;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Incorrect!, Try again.\n");  
                    printf("\n");              
                }   
            
                printf("Question 3\n");  
                //question
                printf("Enter your answer: ");
                scanf("%s", answer3);
            
                if (strcmp(answer3,quiz1Ans3) == 0) {
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    score += 5;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Incorrect!, Try again.\n");  
                    printf("\n");              
                }
                score = (score/15.0)*100.0;
                overallScore = overallScore + score;
                printf("Quiz score is %.1f percent!\n\n", overallScore);
            }
        }

        if (quizNumber == 2) {
            attempts = 0;
            while (overallScore != 100) { 
                attempts++;
                score = 0;
                overallScore=0;
                printf("Quiz 2\n"); 
                printf("Question 1\n"); 
                //question 
                printf("A. True\n");
                printf("B. False\n");
                printf("Enter your answer: ");
                scanf(" %c", &answer1);
            
                if (answer1 == 'B' || answer1 == 'b') {
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    score += 5;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Incorrect!, Try again.\n");  
                    printf("\n");       
                }
                   
                printf("Question 2\n");
                //question
                printf("A. \n");
                printf("B. \n");
                printf("C. \n");
                printf("D. \n");
                printf("Enter your answer: ");
                scanf(" %c", &answer2);

                if (answer2 == 'B' || answer2 == 'b') {
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    score += 5;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Incorrect!, Try again.\n");  
                    printf("\n");              
                }   
            
                printf("Question 3\n");  
                //question
                printf("Enter your answer: ");
                scanf("%s", answer3);
            
                if (strcmp(answer3,quiz1Ans3) == 0) {
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    score += 5;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Incorrect!, Try again.\n");  
                    printf("\n");              
                }
                score = (score/15.0)*100.0;
                overallScore = overallScore + score;
                printf("Quiz score is %.1f percent!\n\n", overallScore);
            }
        }

        if (quizNumber == 3) {
            attempts = 0;
            while (overallScore != 100) { 
                attempts++;
                score = 0;
                overallScore=0;
                printf("Quiz 3\n"); 
                printf("Question 1\n"); 
                //question 
                printf("A. True\n");
                printf("B. False\n");
                printf("Enter your answer: ");
                scanf(" %c", &answer1);
            
                if (answer1 == 'B' || answer1 == 'b') {
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    score += 5;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Incorrect!, Try again.\n");  
                    printf("\n");       
                }
                   
                printf("Question 2\n");
                //question
                printf("A. \n");
                printf("B. \n");
                printf("C. \n");
                printf("D. \n");
                printf("Enter your answer: ");
                scanf(" %c", &answer2);

                if (answer2 == 'B' || answer2 == 'b') {
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    score += 5;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Incorrect!, Try again.\n");  
                    printf("\n");              
                }   
            
                printf("Question 3\n");  
                //question
                printf("Enter your answer: ");
                scanf("%s", answer3);
            
                if (strcmp(answer3,quiz1Ans3) == 0) {
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    score += 5;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Incorrect!, Try again.\n");  
                    printf("\n");              
                }
                score = (score/15.0)*100.0;
                overallScore = overallScore + score;
                printf("Quiz score is %.1f percent!\n\n", overallScore);
            }
        }
            
        attempts = attempts * 15;
        averageScore = i * 5;
        finalScore = averageScore / attempts * 100;
        printf("Average score across all attempts is %.1f percent.\n", finalScore);
        
        preval = quizNumber;
        printf("Would you like to go again y/n? ");
        scanf(" %c", &loop);
        if (loop != 'y'){
            loop = 'n';
            printf("Goodbye!");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also if you are wondering why the questions are empty its because I haven't written them yet, I just wanted to get everything working before I wrote them.

Comment: What is the lucky number for?

Comment: "*the if statements are skipped*". What does that mean exactly? Does it go into an infinete loop? Does the program exit? Something else? Best to show the exact input, expected result and actual result/log.

Comment: You never reset `overallScore`, so the condition `while (overallScore != 100)` fails and the loop is skipped.

Comment: You also don't initialize `overallScore` at the beginning of the program, so that's undefined behavior.

Comment: You only need one `printf()` for any continual block of output (or `puts()` or `fputs()` if no conversion is involved). You can't use `scanf()` correctly unless you ***check the return***. You shouldn't use `scanf()` at all given the pitfalls it contains for new C programmers. Instead use `fgets()` to read each line of user-input into a sufficiently size buffer (character array) and then parsing what you need from the buffer with `sscanf()` avoids all the pitfalls.